# Error in mysql syntax - Insert into query

Tags: mysql, syntax, insert

All the column names are correct and data types should be fine, but this throws:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'desc, owner,
>   burl) VALUES ('1', '2', '3', '4',
>   '5')' at line 1

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO servers (ip, name, desc, owner, burl) VALUES ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO servers (ip, name, `desc`, owner, burl) VALUES ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Make sure you backtick column names that uses special words like DESC

Comment: Thanks very much, didnt know it was a special word

Answer (score 0):

`desc` is a reserved word.

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html